# How to Insert Update Trigger?

Tags: sql-server, triggers, insert-update

I know this is simple question for you. but I didn't find the correct yet.

I have 2 tables `dbo.seat` and `dbo.booking`

this is seat table. I put all list seat in and set status is 0.

[image: this is <code>seat</code> table]

and this is `booking` table. when I did insert then statusBooked by default is 1. and if `[end]` is equal of current time automatically statusBooked will updated to 0.

[image: this is booking table]

I want to make status on `dbo.seat` is reference statusBooked on `dbo.booking` by noSeat. if statusBooked is 1 then status also 1 but when statusBooked is update to 0 then status also updated to 0.

note : I make 2 status(statusBooked and status) for some reason in another case.

How do I do ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trigger has an error at first action](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28534487/trigger-has-an-error-at-first-action)

Answer (score 0):

The following trigger will use the INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE to keep the fields in sync.

```
CREATE TRIGGER tg_booking_update_seat
ON dbo.booking
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE 
AS
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INSERTED) BEGIN

        -- Handle insert or update
        UPDATE Sets SET
            status = Bookings.statusBooked
        FROM dbo.seat Seats
            INNER JOIN INSERTED Bookings
                ON Bookings.noSeat = Seats.noSeat

    END ELSE BEGIN
        -- Handle booking being deleted
        UPDATE Seats SET
            status = 0
        FROM dbo.seat Seats
            INNER JOIN DELETED Bookings
                ON Bookings.noSeat = Seats.noSeat
    END
END
GO
```

**UPDATE** Without delete, your trigger could be simplified to this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tg_booking_update_seat
ON dbo.booking
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    -- Handle insert or update
    UPDATE Sets SET
        status = Bookings.statusBooked
    FROM dbo.seat Seats
        INNER JOIN INSERTED Bookings
END
GO
```

Comment: I don't need delete statement. is it oke if I just delete your `delete` sql statement ? @JasonW

Comment: Absolutely. I added a second option if you don't anticipate needing the delete part of the trigger. You would run risk if you ever manually deleted a booking with statusBooked = 1, the seat would stay status = 1 after the booking was deleted.

Comment: oh I see. it works. but why at the first time I do insert, on table seat is nothing happen(not update status). then if i do the second insert, seat just update it status. so it works for second action on booking table not for first time I do (first time: when all status is still 0). why ?

Comment: I'd have to see your code manipulating the booking table. Let me throw this code into SQL Fiddle to confirm.

Comment: what do you mean ? I don't understand with SQL Fiddle. My manipulating code is same as you give.

Comment: Just a thought - do you have another trigger on booking that is updating the statusBooked based on the [end]? If so, I imaging your issue with the trigger is that you have 2 triggers updating here, and it takes the default value, and the new trigger is not initiated when your other trigger updates the default from 1 to 0. You may have to make your other trigger an `instead of insert` and do the insert yourself to make the triggers play nicely with each other (or incorporate that [end] business logic in both places, which I would try to avoid).

Comment: SQL Fiddle is a neat online tool to test SQL code for various database systems. It's just an online tool that helps illustrate issues or solutions on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I have 3. but I disable 2. so only 1 is active (your code). so what should I change ?

Comment: I think you may need to modify 1 of your existing triggers too. Can you share the code of the trigger on booking doing your business logic on the [end]/bookingStatus?

Comment: it's exacly same as you give above. this is the code `TRIGGER tgBooking_update_seat`
`ON dbo.booking`
`AFTER INSERT, UPDATE`
`AS`
`BEGIN IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INSERTED) BEGIN`
  `-- Handle insert or update`
   `UPDATE Seats SET`
    `status = Bookings.statusBooked`
     `FROM dbo.seat Seats`
      `INNER JOIN INSERTED Bookings`
            `ON Bookings.noSeat = Seats.noSeat`
   `END` 
`END`
`GO`

Comment: Sorry, I meant one of your disabled triggers that is updating your statusBooked from the DEFAULT(1) to 0 if the end date is current time. I think this is the trigger that was conflicting.

Comment: 2 other triggers is same as active trigger. I just try another solution without delete old trigger I have (which is almost correct)). 3 triggers with equal function to avoid risk. I can delete 2 other triggers. because the result is same as you give, has error at first time. so what's the problem ?

Comment: I think the trigger is fine. Here's a sql fiddle where I tried to reproduce the situation and run it through various test cases. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c90af/1/0 - Hope this helps. Not sure if there's anything else I can do from here.

Comment: would you mind if I send you my database by email end please check it ?